# Objeto ResultSet fica null após o try-catch. Java

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch, resultset

eu fiz uma query no meu banco e deu certo, porém não estou conseguinto usar o ResultSet dessa query. Eu debuguei e descobri que ele tem um conteúdo correto, mas ele fica com null depois do try catch onde ele é preenchido:

Vejam os dois print out que eu fiz do rs (ResultSet):

```
public ContaCorrente getConta(int agencia, int numConta) {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM CONTACORRENTE" + " WHERE AGENCIA = ? AND NUMERO = ?";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try (PreparedStatement st = ConexaoComBd.getConectora().getConexao().prepareStatement(query);) {
            st.setInt(COLUNA_AGENCIA, agencia);
            st.setInt(COLUNA_NUMCONTA, numConta);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Result set dentro do try catch: "+rs);//AQUI TUDO CERTO

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro no banco de dados ao consultar conta corrente. Tente novamente"
                    + "ContaCorrenteDAO Linha67");
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.err.println("Erro geral ao consultar conta corrente. Tente novamente ");
        }                                                                                     
         System.out.println("ResultSet após o try catch:" +rs); //AQUI ELE ESTÁ  null
        ContaCorrente c = montarConta(rs);
        return c;
    }
```

Porque isso ocorre? Onde estou errando?

Comment: Fechar a statement causa o fechamento do resultset. Não sei porque dele estar aparentemente nulo, mas fechado ele deve estar. Tente montar a `ContaCorrente` dentro do `try-catch`. Inclusive, bote o resultset para ser auto-fechado no `try-with-resources`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o padrão `AutoClosable` para criar o seu `PreparedStatement`, nesse padrão você cria uma instancia de um obejto que implementa a interface `Closable` no try, sempre que o try finaliza ele dá um close automaticamente nos objetos criados.

O código abaixo funcionará:

```
public ContaCorrente getConta(int agencia, int numConta) {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM CONTACORRENTE" + " WHERE AGENCIA = ? AND NUMERO = ?";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try (PreparedStatement st = ConexaoComBd.getConectora().getConexao().prepareStatement(query);) {
            st.setInt(COLUNA_AGENCIA, agencia);
            st.setInt(COLUNA_NUMCONTA, numConta);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Result set dentro do try catch: "+rs);//AQUI TUDO CERTO
            ContaCorrente c = montarConta(rs);
            return c;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro no banco de dados ao consultar conta corrente. Tente novamente"
                    + "ContaCorrenteDAO Linha67");
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.err.println("Erro geral ao consultar conta corrente. Tente novamente ");
        }                                                                                     
         System.out.println("ResultSet após o try catch:" +rs); //AQUI ELE ESTÁ  null
         return null;
    }
```

Comment: O auto-fechamento não justifica a nulidade do objeto, apesar de sim, esse código ter tudo para funcionar.

Comment: Certo, resolvi. Então o PreparedStatement implementa essa interface Autocloseable né? E ele sempre vai se comportar assim, certo? Pra minha query não sumir após o try catch teria que utilizar outro tipo de classe né?